# Update a field which is inside array of array in MongoDb using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to update a field which is inside a nested array or list. Using .Net Mongo Driver.

My Data structure is like:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "602cb1627661691f87bb1e6e"
  },
  "Events": [
    {
      "_id": "5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38",
      "Roles": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "6017a4616609ff520ad2cd26"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Sessions": [],
      "IsProfileVisible": false,
      "Aois": [],
      "ViewOrder": 1,
      "HelloWorldVideo": {
        "Duration": 0,
        "GroupId": "5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38",
        "TagId": "TESTING",
        "Title": "Testing title",
        "VideoUrls": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webm",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "603752797904007c5cc93e78"
        },
        "ProcessedVideoUrls": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webmProcessed",
        "TagTypeId": null,
        "Thumbnail": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webm",
        "VideoType": "1",
        "VttUrl": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webmvtt"
      },
      "SoapboxVideos": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "60373e34ad2fe9624705f40d"
          },
          "VideoPaths": null,
          "Title": "Testing title",
          "TagId": "TESTING",
          "TagTypeId": null,
          "Thumbnail": null,
          "GroupId": "5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38",
          "VideoImageUrl": null,
          "VideoType": null,
          "VideoUrls": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webm",
          "ProcessedVideoUrls": null,
          "VideoId": null,
          "VttUrl": null,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Duration": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "603740d4ad2fe9624705f40e"
          },
          "VideoPaths": null,
          "Title": "Testing title",
          "TagId": "TESTING",
          "TagTypeId": null,
          "Thumbnail": null,
          "GroupId": "DigitalEvents_5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38",
          "VideoImageUrl": null,
          "VideoType": null,
          "VideoUrls": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream1.webm",
          "ProcessedVideoUrls": null,
          "VideoId": null,
          "VttUrl": null,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Duration": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "603752ce7904007c5cc93e79"
          },
          "VideoPaths": null,
          "Title": "Testing title",
          "TagId": "TESTING",
          "TagTypeId": null,
          "Thumbnail": null,
          "GroupId": "DigitalEvents_5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38",
          "VideoImageUrl": null,
          "VideoType": null,
          "VideoUrls": "https://cdn.azureedge.net/3734/helloworld/elephants-dream.webm",
          "ProcessedVideoUrls": null,
          "VideoId": null,
          "VttUrl": null,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Duration": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

Since it requires two positional operators, I am following below method. I am trying to update ProcessedVideoUrls, VttUrl inside SoapboxVideos list.

```
updateResult = await _userCollection
    .UpdateOneAsync(
        x => x.Id == updateVideoPath.UserId, // 602cb1627661691f87bb1e6e
        Builders<UserModel>.Update.Set("Events.$[event].SoapboxVideos.$[soapbox].ProcessedVideoUrls", updateVideoPath.VideoUrls)
            .Set("Events.$[event].SoapboxVideos.$[soapbox].VttUrl", updateVideoPath.VttUrl),
        new UpdateOptions
        {
            ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
            {
                new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("event.Id", updateVideoPath.EventId)), // 5ffd8d7f7d553920b9608f38
                new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("soapbox.Id", updateVideoPath.Id)) // 603752ce7904007c5cc93e79
            }
        }
    );
```

When it get executed, I am not getting any exceptions as such.. Rather I am getting MatchedCount as 1 and ModifiedCount as 0. Please note that the field which I am trying to update defenitly has value, which is not the existing value too.

Any help to understand the issue is appreciated. I am using Mongo driver version number 2.11.6

Answer (score 0):

Following changes in the code resolved the issue

```
new UpdateOptions
{
    ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
    {
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("event._id",  updateVideoPath.EventId)),
        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("soapbox._id", ObjectId.Parse( updateVideoPath.Id)))
    }
});
```

Actual issue was the Soapbox Id type, it is ObjectId and I have used property "`soapbox.Id`" instead of "`soapbox._id`". Those changes resolved the issue.